# What is a nightly build in solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, error, compilation, compiler

I have received an error that says so:

> ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current
> compiler is 0.8.3+commit.8d00100c.Emscripten.clang) - note that
> nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released
> version -->
> https://github.com/ConsenSysMesh/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol:1:1:
> | 1 | pragma solidity ^0.4.23; |

Also on the remix interface, on the solidity compiler page, I can see an "Include nightly builds" checkbox.

So what is  nightly build?

Comment: This is a more general concept in computer science, it doesn't apply to the Solidity programming language exclusively. See this: [What does 'Nightly Builds' mean?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56490/what-does-nightly-builds-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is about nightly builds in general and not specific to solidity.
A nightly build, in general, is a build of a version, that is not finished yet.
So there might be more bugs or missing features.
It is basically a build of the current work in progress.
It is called nightly build because it is common to automatically build them from the current source code at night, when developers are (probably) not working on it.

Answer (score 1):

You error is not related to nightly builds. One of your files (SafeMath.sol) requires a compiler version (`pragma solidity ^0.4.23`) lower than the one you selected (`0.8.3`).